# ¿Cómo guardar y descargar un archivo asp.net mvc C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un método que registra un ticket y unos de los campos input:file ello guarda una imagen en bytes en la base de datos.

Lo que deseo hacer es guardar en la base de datos un archivo de cualquier tipo (word,pdf,excel,jpg) en bytes . También deseo descargar ese mismo archivo.

Método guardar

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult registrarTicket(Ticket ticket)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase filebase = Request.Files[0];
            WebImage image = new WebImage(filebase.InputStream);
            ticket.Imagen = image.GetBytes();
            ticket.Fecha_Reg = DateTime.Now;
            ticket.Area = "DESARROLLO";
            ticket.Est_ticket = "Registrado";
            ticket.Flag_est = true;

            this._repo.Agregar(ticket);
            this._repo.Guardar();
            return Json(new { data = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Método descargar

```
public FileResult descargar(int id)
        {
            var obj = _repo.TraerUno(id);
            byte[] imagen = obj.Imagen;

            var filename = string.Format("CapturaError{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".jpg";

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagen);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return File(ms, "image/jpg", filename);
        }
```

Clase Ticket

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Num_ticket { get; set; }
        public string Nom_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Correo_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Telf_usu_reg { get; set; }
        public string Tit_problema { get; set; }
        public string Desc_problema { get; set; }
        public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Prioridad { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Reg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Mod_reg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Asig { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Atencion { get; set; }
        public string Est_ticket { get; set; }
        public string Usu_asig { get; set; }
        public string Usu_atencion { get; set; }
        public string Respuesta_atencion { get; set; }
        public string CodUsuario { get; set; }
        public Boolean Flag_est { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes el byte[] del archivo para que el resto

```
    public FileResult descargar(int id)
    {
        var obj = _repo.TraerUno(id);
        byte[] imagen = obj.Imagen;

        var filename = string.Format("CapturaError{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}.jpg", DateTime.Now);

        return File(imagen, "image/jpg", filename);
    }
```

si el File() no permite enviar byte[] se podria usar el FileContentResult

Comment: Estimado leandro como retornaría el método return file(imagen)

Comment: El byte[] ya es la imagen en si misma, no necesitas ningun Image para generar el archivo. Si tomas ese byte[] y lo usas directo con el File.WriteAllBytes() a un archivo tendras la imagen

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes()  recibe 2 parámetros el primer parametro que valor se debe ingresar y el segundo es los bytes del archivo. Disculpa la molestia soy nuevo viendo la carga de archivos.

Comment: Yo lo deseo descargar en el navegador cada vez que se de click a un botón.

Comment: Lo del WriteAllBytes() lo mencione a modo de prueba, si querias validar que el byte[] era la imagen, no tienes que usarlo

Comment: el `return File()` no te deja pasarle por parametro un byte[] ? sino te deja usa el `FileContent()`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113541/discussion-between-dum-and-leandro-tuttini).